# How are poles and equators geometrically defined in a 3D matrix (curved space) that is a part of a 4D matrix (hyperspace)?

Tags: astronomy, curvature, geometry, spacetime-dimensions

Our planet's surface is a curved 2D that has an infinite number of equators although we chose just one for vital geom. orientation purposes. Every of those equators has its 2 conjugate poles that can be defined as points that do not change distance from the observer as he moves along that equator. He just notices that, as he rotates around them that all of them spin. My question is about a 3D curved space as a part of a 4D manifold that is expressed flat just for simplicity. So, as if in curved 2D somebody can rotate around 2 points (poles) simultaneously is that allowed in curved 3D? I just tried to imagine a ring(collection of poles) around a path (equator) which points (poles) cannot change their distance from a space traveler that is moving along the equator and similarly to 2D he notices these points on the 'polar ring' are spinning paralel to his motion as he moves along the equator but do not change distance from him though. So if somebody picks a ring as a collection of points but that are more close to the person moving on the equator he would see those points 'behaving' very much similarly as points of an Euclidian flat space or simply said he would see that they and the entire ring is left behind the traveler as he moves straight on the equator which would not be the case for a ring positioned on the 3D pole which should remain firm and its plane being orthogonal to the observer's direction...*So to repeat again the question:* **Is it possible rotate or orbit simultaneously around more points in a curved 3D as it is possible in curved 2D**?

[image]

[image]